# Confirm service credentials changed

Tags: c#, service

I am using the following code to change the credentials of a windows service. Before I display the message that credentials were successfully changed, I want to confirm the new credentials have been applied. How can I do that?

```
using (ManagementObject service = new ManagementObject(new ManagementPath(objPath)))
                {
                    object[] wmiParams = new object[11];
                    wmiParams[6] = _username;
                    wmiParams[7] = _password;
                    service.InvokeMethod("Change", wmiParams);
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    //check if new credentials in order
                    //Console.WriteLine("Service credentials changed");
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new credentials won't apply until you restart the service, and I suggest you use the ServiceController instead of WMI.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check the returned object from `InvokeMethod` and just handle errors without any further complexity.  The only issue is working out what returned value implies success.

```
object result = service.InvokeMethod("Change", wmiParams);

// if result 'is bad', handle error
```